# Need to set difference of two dates fields in other column inside same table using single MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns(`date_start` and `date_due`) which contain dates values.

Is it possible to get their difference(in hours) and set it in another column(`duration_hours`) using `single UPDATE query`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function.

```
UPDATE mytable SET duration_hours = TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, date_start, date_due) where date_start is not null OR date_due is not null or date_start !='' OR date_due !=''
```

source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: @Star empty or null? if both you should write an `if`

Comment: @Star updated my answer.

Comment: @Star if it works, can you set it as answer?